# Why this simple regex/Scanner is not working?

Tags: java, regex

I have to resolve the next exercise:

Create a keyboard scanner in which the tokens are unsigned integers, and write the code to determine the sum of the integers.

Note: -5 will be scanned as the unsigned integer 5, and the minus sign will be skipped over as a delimiter

this is my solution (not working) :

```
   import java.util.*;

public class testing{

    public static void main( String[] argv ){

        testing p = new testing();
    }

    public testing(){

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String regex = "\\s+|-";
        myScanner.useDelimiter(regex);

        int sum = 0;

        while(myScanner.hasNextInt()){

            int partial = myScanner.nextInt();
            sum += partial; 
        }

        System.out.println(sum); 
    }
}
```

The problem with my solution is that it is working only for positive integers or negative integer (only first input) added to positive integers.
for example:

```
-2
3
4
f (used to stop the program)
```

will retrieve 9.
but

```
3
-2
```

will stop the program and retrieve 3

I am trying to understand the reason of this behavior but not luck so far.

Comment: Since you are working strictly with numeric values and performing numeric operations, you might want to consider using numerical functions, primarily `Math.abs()` methods.

Comment: @npinti that would work but the exercise requires " the minus sign will be skipped over as a delimiter" so i think method "useDelimiter" should be used to resolve the problem

Comment: I thin your regex should be `"\\s+|\\s*-"` (or what sheltem says, this will consume whitespaces up to - and at least 1 character, sheltem consumes at least one character and any number of - and whitespace)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using an OR in the regex, which means it just consumes the line break and then stops at the '-', because it's not consumed as a delimiter any more.

The input your scanner sees is:

> -2\n3\n4\nf

'f' is the first thing after an integer that does not match your pattern of whitespaces **OR** one minus.

The second pattern though requires **both** to be matched vs your delimiter:

> 3\n-2

So the line break (white space) is matched versus your delimiter pattern and the minus remains unmatched. Since it's not an Integer .hasNextInt() returns false.

A repeatable group of whitespaces and minus works as you intend:

```
final String regex = "[\\s-]+";
```

This might end up accepting more than your exercise requires, like multiple minus signs in front of a number. If that is not acceptable, you can of course limit the minus to one occurance after an indeterminate amount of whitespaces:

```
final String regex = "[\\s]*-?";
```

The '?' means "once or not at all" and limits the occurances of minuses.

Edit:

As @maraca pointed out in a comment, my previously proposed solution only works for single digit numbers, as the pattern accepts the empty string as well. The solution that works for numbers >9 as well is:

```
final String regex = "\\s+|\\s*-";
```

What it does is consume either one or more whitespaces **OR** zero or more whitespaces followed by a minus sign.

Turns out even small things like these can be rather difficult to do right. -.-

Comment: Why does the line break consumed in the first case but not in the second?

Comment: In his first example there is *only* a linebreak to consume and not also a minus. His pattern only consumes one OR the other, never both. So linebreak + minus is not consumed by his delimiter.

Comment: Thank you, though I keep going back to edit for clarification because I find myself typing too fast and then describing it wrong. :C Now it should be done...!

Comment: If the pattern is put into the OP's code, any word like "hello" will simply exit the program with the result 0. Of course this pattern is not applicable for splitting strings, but that is not part of the question any way.

Comment: Yeah... my version might still need some braces, but I'm glad it helped you solve your problem. -.- I even switched to "\\s*(\\s|-)" in my own implementation, which might be better to understand. Answering this question reminded me why I like to keep away from regexes!

Answer (score -1):

You can solve by catching `InputMismatchException` like this:

```
public Testing(){

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String regex = "\\s+|-";
        myScanner.useDelimiter(regex);

        int sum = 0;

        while(myScanner.hasNext()){
            int partial = 0;
            try{
                partial = myScanner.nextInt();
            } catch(InputMismatchException e){
                continue;
            }
            sum += partial; 
        }

        System.out.println(sum); 
}
```

The issue is you are trying to parse a int but you receive a "-".